# Using Ramda `range` to duplicate, but need to interject at every 3rd (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ramda.js

I'm currently using Ramda to output a `Material-UI CheckCircle` for every instance of a `perk` a record has. They can have a maximum of 18, so I am also using it to keep counting `past the perk` to a max of `18` to show the potential maximum.

```
{R.range(0, this.props.perkProgress).map(() => <CheckCircle key={uid()} /> )}
            {R.range(this.props.perkProgress, 18).map(() => <CheckBoxOutline key={uid()} /> )}
```

These two lines work perfectly, however I need to also interject something after every 'third' one - Rather it's a box, or a checkmark. Since I don't believe I can do with Ramda, how could I write this in a normal JS sense (Or wrap this inside of a function; either one) to get the output I need?

`this.props.perkProgress` is always an integer between 0 and 18.

If they have '5', I would expect 5 checkmarks, and 13 empty squares.

Adding a [terrible drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOQR3.jpg) of the currently functioning section, and the desired endresult :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using Ramda by first splitting the list of elements using [`R.splitEvery`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#splitEvery) then adding the separator between each split list using [`R.intersperse`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#intersperse) and finally joining the split lists back together with [`R.unnest`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#unnest).

(n.b. I've swapped out your JSX with strings below for the sake of brevity)

```js
// inserts `sep` between every `n` elements of a list `xs`
const separateEvery = (sep, n, xs) =>
  R.unnest(R.intersperse([sep], R.splitEvery(n, xs)))

const genElements = (totalSize, progress) =>
  separateEvery('Separator', 3, R.concat(
    R.repeat('CheckCircle', progress),
    R.repeat('CheckBoxOutline', totalSize - progress)
  ))

console.log(genElements(18, 7))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

---

*updates in response to comments below*

---

One approach to adding a key to each of the generated elements would be to map over each with `React.cloneElement`.

```
const genElementsWithKey = R.pipe(
  genElements,
  R.addIndex(R.map)((el, key) => React.cloneElement(el, {key}))
)
```

Alternatively, if you didn't want to use `cloneElement` for some reason then you could swap out `R.intersperse` using `R.zipWith` to create a unique separator element to insert between each group of elements.

```js
const createCircle = _ => '<CheckCircle key={uid()} />'
const createCheckBox = _ => '<CheckBoxOutline key={uid()} />'
const createSeparator = _ => '<Separator key={uid()} />'

const genElements = (totalSize, progress) => {
  const splitEls = R.splitEvery(3, R.concat(
    R.map(createCircle, R.range(0, progress)),
    R.map(createCheckBox, R.range(progress, totalSize))
  ))
  
  const firstSplitGroup = splitEls[0]
  const remainingSplitGroups = R.tail(splitEls)
  
  // create a list of separators matching the number of elements in remainingSplitGroups
  const separators = R.map(createSeparator, R.range(0, remainingSplitGroups.length))
  
  return R.concat(
    // keep the first split group as is
    firstSplitGroup,
    // prepend a separator to each of the remaining split groups
    R.unnest(R.zipWith(R.prepend, separators, remainingSplitGroups))
  )
}

console.log(genElements(18, 7))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This solution is beautiful but `R.repeat()` clones the element which means I get a `key` warning if I leave it blank, or a `non-unique` key warning if I populate it. How do you get around that? I tried using `progress` but there will be multiple entities running this, so `progress` isn't unique either.

Comment: Using your logic but with `R.range()` resolved the issue. Beautiful solution; Thanks - How were you able to figure out which functions to use for this? Or is it an experience thing or does the Documentation have a search filter I am unaware of?

Comment: I'm one of the contributors of Ramda, but in terms of breaking it down "after every 'third' one" signals to make use of `R.splitEvery` and "I need to also interject something" signals to make use of `R.intersperse`. In terms of searching the docs, when dealing with a list of things you can type `List` in the search field (or click the `List` label next to one of the functions in the sidebar) to only show functions that operate over lists which makes it easier to find functions that you may not know the name for (I still forget the names for some of the functions myself).

Comment: That's an awesome tip, thanks: Since I don't want to modify my original question and technically it was answered (Although I have a bug now) - Is there a way to include a unique ID with the `seperateEvery`? I ask because I replaced `Separator` with a component and now I am unable to assign a unique key to that element.

Comment: @DNorthrup - I've updated the answer to include some examples of generating unique keys for each separator.

Comment: Thank you so much for this fix! I wasn't away it was this simple. This is beautiful!